# Homestead config does not work

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I created this config for homestead. When I load http://loc.medifaktor I just get returned: "No input file is specified"

The local folder structure is correct as mentioned below, so I see all files and they are accessible. Why does it return this error?

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/Development/Source/
      to: /home/vagrant/Source

sites:
    - map: loc.medifaktor
      to: /home/vagrant/Source/MFServer/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

and this is my etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.10.10   loc.medifaktor
127.0.0.1       loc.medifaktor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to ssh into the VM and then run:

```
serve loc.medifaktor /home/vagrant/Source/MFServer/public
```

Comment: dos2unix: /vagrant/scripts/serve.sh: No such file or directory
dos2unix: Skipping /vagrant/scripts/serve.sh, not a regular file.
bash: /vagrant/scripts/serve.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: How would I need to change the config then? The local files are in ~/Documents/Development/Source/MFServer

Comment: try this first before the serve commad `cp /vagrant/scripts/serve-laravel.sh /vagrant/scripts/serve.sh` then run the serve command again.